# ASP.NET page is blocking in code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, concurrency, blocking

An ASP.NET page is blocking inside the code behind, when accessed a second time within the same session.
Two calls from within the same session are sort of serialized, but shouldn't.

It does not help to disable the session state for that page:

```
    <%@ Page    EnableSessionState="False" %>
    ...
    <div runat="server" id="lblMsg"></div>
```

Code behind part:

```
    using System;

    namespace SysWeb
    {
        public partial class BlockTest2Page : System.Web.UI.Page
        {
            protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
            {
                // show time
                this.lblMsg.InnerHtml += DateTime.Now.ToString() + "<br />";
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(4000);
                this.lblMsg.InnerHtml += DateTime.Now.ToString() + "<br />";
            }
        }
    }
```

When you open two tabs in a browser (tested in Firefox and Chrome), and call the same page with the same URL, the times shown on each page will show that one call is blocked until the first is done completely. The start/end times will not overlap, even if you start both calls at the same time.

Why? How can this be changed?

When using a third browser with a different session, nothing is blocked, the start/end-times shown overlap as intended.
Using a different ?-querystring-param allows concurrent execution even in the same browser. How can asp.net be configured to execute such calls parallel, and not sequential?

Comment: Is this happening with Cassini, IIS Express or real IIS? If not real IIS, could you try with that as well?

Comment: I'm using IIS 6.0 on Windows 2003 R2 with ASP.NET 4.0.
I'll test it on a Windows 2008 R2 soon, and add the results.

Comment: Same result on Windows 2008 R2 with ASP.NET 4.0 and "Integrated Pipeline".

Comment: It would be nice if anyone can confirm this behaviour.
The web project is compiled with VS2010 into a dll inside the bin-directory.

Comment: Idea: Possibly it's a limitation (or feature :-)) of the current browsers? They'll simply queue up the second call, till the first is finished?